# FirebaseApp.configure() crash after updating the pods

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, appdelegate, firebase-analytics

[image: Left Side Bar][image: My info plist file]Last three hours I have been struggling with one problem in my App. I've just updated my pods and when the `FirebaseApp.configure()` method is called in **appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, app crashes immediately. I have two targets in my project and each of them has its own **Google-Info.plist** file. The error is always the same, whether there is internet connection or not.

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.installations', reason: 'The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the defaultFirebaseApp instance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).**

I tracked where the crash happens in the ***Pods/FirebaseCore/FIRApp.m***

```
[firAnalyticsClass performSelector:startWithConfigurationSelector
                            withObject:[FIRConfiguration sharedInstance].analyticsConfiguration
                            withObject:_options];
```

I downloaded latest the plist files and copied still the same error.
What should I do now? To get back to old version of the Firebase library?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your Google-service plist? Like an image of it in ur left side menu

Comment: I've just added.

Comment: I meant to provide an image of the ”file” not the inside of the file :)

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: You changed name on them?

Comment: Yes and  I reach them using Bundle and add them to FirebaseApp.configure(withoptions)

Comment: Whenever you download a Googleservice they HAVE to remain their orgiinal name. Download a new one and remobe the (1) if any.

Comment: Or change back to the original name. I’m also not even sure if you can have 2 googleService. Why do you have two?

Comment: I don't think that you understand the situation, you can naturally have as many as Google-Info.plist you want. As long as you save all the bundles in Firebase, you can and should use them without a problem.

Comment: Please check this link [ https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects ]

Comment: Could not find the website. But hmmm. That seems strange if it’s crashing... I’m on my phone so hard to see in a fully perspective

Comment: The link has been edited

Comment: Thanks, Mehmet. I do not have a solution for this then :/ I’m sorry for wasting your time & good luck!

Comment: No problem. Thanks